# Detect trigger for closeEvent in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a PyQt GUI which has multiple ways of being closed. Two such ways are if they X out of the window, or if they complete a certain task. My class, which extends from `QMainWindow`, implements the `closeEvent` method.

In the case when the use X's out of the window, I want to ask them if they're sure they want to quit, then do some cleanup and close if they say yes.

In the case where they complete the certain task, I just want to do the cleanup and quit.

Right now my `closeEvent` looks like this:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    # Ask the user if they actually want to quit using custom message box
    msg = MessageBox(self, 'Are you sure you want to quit?', title = 'Quit', buttons = QMessageBox.Yes|QMessageBox.No)
    if msg.reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
        #
        # Do some cleanup here
        #
        super().close()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

With this certain setup, it always asks if they are sure they want to close, which is necessary for when they X out of the window. When they've completed the specific task, I know they want to close and just want to jump to the cleanup and closing process, without asking this question.

My idea would be that in some close cases, I direct them to a separate function which does it's necessary tasks, then calls the close method. But the problem here is, I don't know how to direct the X out process to a different method before calling the close method. As it is right now, it always asks if they're sure they want to quit because this is needed as part of the X out closing method.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You could be more precise in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method of solution is to close your application without running `closeEvent`, for this you can use the function `qApp.quit()`.

For example in the following script can be closed by two methods: the first is a new button called btn, and the second the button X. For the first case we connect it to a slot that calls a dialog, if that is accepted I close the Application with qApp.quit, the second case is similar to the one you implement.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        btn = QPushButton("close")
        self.setCentralWidget(btn)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.closeByButton)

    def closeByButton(self):
        msgBox = QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setText("new Method")
        msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Cancel | QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No);
        msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.Yes);
        if msgBox.exec_() == QMessageBox.Yes:
            qApp.quit()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        msgBox = QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setText("Button X Method")
        msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Cancel | QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No);
        msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.Yes);
        if msgBox.exec_() == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This could work. My main difficulty is that the class I have this GUI in is in a separate file from the QApplication object so it's not in scope for me. It would be ugly and tedious, but I could pass it along the whole way. Is there anyway that the QMainWindow knows about the QApplication object?

Comment: qApp is accessible from all sides.